# Let $n>1$ be an integer and $f(x) \in Z[x].$ is $\frac{Z_n[x]}{\left(\frac{(n,f(x))}{(n)}\right)}= \frac{Z_n[x]}{(f(x))}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $n>1$ be an integer and $f(x) \in Z[x].$

is  $$ \frac{Z_n[x]}{\left(\frac{(n,f(x))}{(n)}\right)}= \frac{Z_n[x]}{(f(x))}$$

---

What Im trying to show to myself is that

when $n>1$ be an integer and $f(x) \in Z[x]$

show $$ Z_n[x]/(f(x))\cong Z[x]/(n,f(x))$$

---

have seen on similar problems to use the third isomorphism theorem

**third isomorphism theorem**

Let $I$ and $J$ be an ideal of a ring R with $I \subset J$

then   $J/I$ is an Ideal of $R/I$ and $$ R/J \cong \frac{(R/I)}{(J/I)}$$

---

there are two options $(n) \subset (n,f(x))$ or $(f(x)) \subset (n,f(x))$

will use option 1 $(n)=I$ $J=(n,f(x))$  and $R=Z[x]$

so  if the statemet from above is true

$$ Z[x]/(n,f(x)) \cong \left. \frac{Z[x]}{(n)} \right/ \frac{(n,f(x))}{(n)} =  \frac{Z_n[x]}{  \frac{(n,f(x))}{(n)} } = \frac{Z_n[x]}{\langle f(x)\rangle}$$

---